# Count frequency by ID and numbers in range

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe (30 rows) with 2 columns: ID and foldChange.
I want to count for each ID how many values it got in total, and how many are smaller, larger or in between -2.5 and 2.5.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneB", 
"GeneA", "GeneC", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneC", "GeneB", 
"GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneC", "GeneB", 
"GeneE", "GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneE", "GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneD", 
"GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneA", "GeneA"), foldChange = c(-5.1600815, 
0.2356138, 0.2994572, -1.5287992, 1.1800347, 1.1895113, 0.9141108, 
0.9755535, 1.8635915, 3.2866096, -0.8132076, 3.6282988, 0.9746175, 
2.023966, -2.1919911, 0.5949673, 1.2257918, -1.3623925, -0.2271354, 
1.2196725, 0.8754267, -2.2295773, 1.1893983, 1.5627226, 1.5744269, 
0.7333871, 10.8201467, 0.7695394, -1.3149008, -1.3092684)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))


ID  foldChange
GeneA   -5.1600815
GeneA   0.2356138
GeneA   0.2994572
GeneA   -1.5287992
GeneB   1.1800347
GeneA   1.1895113
GeneC   0.9141108
GeneA   0.9755535
GeneA   1.8635915
```

I can see the frequency of each ID like this

```
freq_df = df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = n()) 

ID      n
GeneA   10
GeneB   5
GeneC   5
GeneD   8
GeneE   2
```

In order to get how many values per ID, have foldChange < -2.5, > 2.5 and in between those two values I am doing this:

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>%
    summarize(up = sum(df$foldChange >= 2.5),
              down = sum(df$foldChange <= -2.5),
              nosig = sum(df$foldChange > -2.5 & df$foldChange < 2.5))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
  up down nosig
1  3    1    26
```

Yet as you can see is not working, and it's just calculating for the entire df.

desired output:

```
ID  n   up  down    nosig
GeneA   10  1   1   8
GeneB   5   1   0   4
GeneC   5   0   0   5
GeneD   8   1   0   7
GeneE   2   0   0   2
```

Hope someone can help me troubleshoot this.
Thanks!

Comment: Try removing all `df$`. With them you are referring to the entire df, not to each group.

Comment: Not working ```Error in eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'foldChange' not found```

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios are you specifying `dplyr::summarize` on both occasions?

Comment: @AllanCameron That did it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you can include the `n()` into the `summarise()` where you calculate `up`, `down`, `nosig` and as @Rui Barradas mentioned removing the `df$` within `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(ID = c("GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneB", 
                      "GeneA", "GeneC", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneA", "GeneC", "GeneB", 
                      "GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneC", "GeneB", 
                      "GeneE", "GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneE", "GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneD", 
                      "GeneD", "GeneD", "GeneA", "GeneA"), foldChange = c(-5.1600815, 
                                                                          0.2356138, 0.2994572, -1.5287992, 1.1800347, 1.1895113, 0.9141108, 
                                                                          0.9755535, 1.8635915, 3.2866096, -0.8132076, 3.6282988, 0.9746175, 
                                                                          2.023966, -2.1919911, 0.5949673, 1.2257918, -1.3623925, -0.2271354, 
                                                                          1.2196725, 0.8754267, -2.2295773, 1.1893983, 1.5627226, 1.5744269, 
                                                                          0.7333871, 10.8201467, 0.7695394, -1.3149008, -1.3092684)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                          -30L))
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(
    n = n(),
    up = sum(foldChange >= 2.5),
    down = sum(foldChange <= -2.5),
    nosig = sum(foldChange > -2.5 & foldChange < 2.5)
  )

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  ID        n    up  down nosig
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 GeneA    10     1     1     8
2 GeneB     5     1     0     4
3 GeneC     5     0     0     5
4 GeneD     8     1     0     7
5 GeneE     2     0     0     2
```

Comment: ```Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: i'm not getting the error on my end, what version of R and dplyr are you using? also other packages loaded?

Comment: This 
dplyr_1.0.2
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) Thanks

Comment: It worked when I added ```dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
    dplyr::summarize(....)```
Thanks !!

Comment: glad to hear, likely naming conflicts with the `summarize` function

Comment: Thanks a lot still :)

Answer (score 1):

Pls try this

```
df%>%
    group_by(ID)%>%
    summarise(n = length(foldChange),
              up = length(foldChange[foldChange>=2.5]),
              down = length(foldChange[foldChange<= -2.5]),
              nosig = length(foldChange[foldChange> -2.5 & foldChange < 2.5])
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot!
 So in my machine it doest work, but I think is a dplyr problem. It only works if I write ```dplyr::summarize```

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios Have you loaded the package with `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: Yes, but that's how I usually load the others ones too. I also loaded plyr, I am wondering if that would create a problem?